# I want to hide video download button from control list in android browser

Tags: php, android, cross-browser

I am working on video project where i want to hide download option from all android browser. i already tried css trick to hide media controls but it wont work any browser except Google chrome

Answer (score 0):

> i want to hide download option from all android browser

By definition, this is not possible. Web browsers are written by other programmers, and those programmers can do whatever they want. If those programmers want to offer some sort of download or save-as option, those programmers can do so. You do not get a vote.

Comment: But then how can i prevent the vide file from being downloaded on mobile devices

Comment: @Omkar: Don't serve it to mobile devices via a Web site. Hiding the download option would not help; it will be trivial for people to find the URL to the video and download it separately.